# Quiting the print dialog-pyqt

Tags: python, printing, pyqt

I defined  a print function using QPrinter and QDialog. However, when I launch the printer dialog and then press cancel, the entire mainwindow goes into not responding mode. I have tried to do `QtGui.QPrintDialog.close()` but does not work.

Code:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QButton(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.name='me'
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.calluser)
    def calluser(self):
        Appli=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        printer= QtGui.QPrinter()
        doc=QtGui.QTextDocument("Set local variables in this printing slot." )
        dialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog(printer)
        dialog.setModal(True)
        dialog.setWindowTitle("Print Document" )
        if dialog.exec_() == True:
            doc.print_(printer)

# dialog.addEnabledOption(QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintSelection)


def demo_QButton():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tb = QButton()
    tb.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__=='__main__':
    demo_QButton()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a new application in the `calluser` method. Delete or comment the line:

```
Appli=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

and try again. I think this time your main window will remain responsive.